# Tortoisesvn cannot commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

Hi I've just upgraded from 1.5 of Tortoisesvn  to 1.6 and most of my repos seem ok.
But I have one where the icons are there as expected but when I try to commit a particular file I get there have been no changes.

I've tried a cleanup and even trying to commit all the files but that just leaves the commit back hanging on Please Wait Check for modifications has similar results as well.

I've tried restarting my computer as well.

Sorry and differences are still in there and I can view them

Any ideas would be great.
Thanks
Richard

Comment: Maybe repo address has changes? Can you describe your errors a little bit in details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly the server is at 1.6 and I'm now at 1.6.
The problem - just to reiterate is this I have a file the I have changed.
Tortoise client side and Iassume server side notice this and give me my red ! symbol.
I click the file and attempt to submit just that one. It won't

The workaround
You need to select at least 2 files and then commit and then yay it come up with box and all is good again.

It's really annoying.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use TortoiseSVN, but I've plenty of experience with SVN in linux and freebsd. If something like this happened to me, I would try checking out a new copy, then copying the changed file over to the fresh checkout and trying to commit it then. Hope that helps!

Comment: I second this. Sometimes the working copy gets corrupted and this workaround is quite simply.

Comment: Yeah. If at all possible, start the checkout from scratch. It's the cure in 95% of cases

Answer (score 1):

Is this from a 1.5 working copy or a 1.6 working copy?  I try to make sure everything is committed before upgrading the server.

Answer (score 0):

SVN 1.5 & 1.6 don't play well together. From your question I suppose that you just updated your client. You may have to update client and server. Have a look at the following [link](http://ferventcoder.com/archive/2009/06/10/subversion-1.6-tree-conflicts-and-the-incompatibility-of-subversion-1.5.aspx).